# Hive Query doesnt allow >= in subquery in the where clause

Tags: sql, hive, subquery, hiveql

I have a table (umt_date) which generates dates and I need to use this date in the second query to get all data greater than equal to the date in umt_date table

```
umt_date
----------------------------
|processdate||processname|
----------------------------
| 2020-06-01 | A         |
----------------------------
| 2020-06-01 | B         |
```

when I perform the sql

```
select * from main_table
where processdate >= (select processdate from umt_date where processname='A')
```

I get the following error

**SQL Error [40000] [42000]: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException Line 0:-1 Unsupported SubQuery Expression 'processdate': Only SubQuery expressions that are top level conjuncts are allowed**

Since we do not have any common columns we cannot perform a join as well. Whats the alternative for this ?

Comment: what version of hive you are using?

Answer (score 1):

If subquery returns single row, use cross join:

```
select m.* 
     from main_table m
          cross join (select processdate from umt_date where processname='A') t
where m.processdate >= t.processdate
```

And if the subquery returns more than one row, use join on some condition. cross join is not good in this case because it will duplicate data, though WHERE may filter duplicated rows

Comment: I cheked the query performance with a hardcoded date vs the cross join and the cross join is 3 times more time consuming than the normal one. So the cross join introduces a performance issue

Comment: @DhirajTayade Yes. it really does.  And it is expected, right? Because hardcoded date query scans only one table. and does not join at all. You can use shell to execute subquery to get date and to pass that date to second query as a parameter

Comment: using the hivevars also doesnt help, since Hive doesnt evaluate the variable before subsitution.

Comment: @DhirajTayade Yes, you cannot do it in the same script. use shell. calculate date using one hive script and pass it to another one

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `WITH` clause like below

```
 WITH PROCESSA_SUBQ AS(
   select processdate from umt_date where processname='A'
 )
 SELECT a.* FROM main_table as a
 INNER JOIN
 PROCESSA_SUBQ as b
 ON 1=1    -- always true join condition, can be ignored.
 where a.processdate >= b.processdate
```

or you could get a boolean condition check too:

```
WITH PROCESSA_SUBQ AS(
   select processdate from umt_date where processname='A'
 )
 SELECT X.* FROM (
 SELECT a.*, (a.processdate>=b.processdate) as check FROM main_table as a
 INNER JOIN
 PROCESSA_SUBQ as b
 ON 1=1  -- always true join condition, can be ignored.
 ) as X where X.check = true
```

Comment: INNER jOIN without ON condition is a CROSS JOIN

Comment: Agreed. But since processdate returns a single row, it doesn't really matter.

Comment: You really doing cross join and it will be less confusing.

Comment: there you go. added the joining condition.

Comment: I cheked the query performance with a hardcoded date vs the cross join and the cross join is 3 times more time consuming than the normal one. So the cross join introduces a performance issue

Comment: Ofcourse cross join is a bottleneck and the solution presented to you is in line the question asked. According to your question, i don't see anything mentioned about using a hardcoded date or performance related queries.

Comment: The query mentioned does introduce a cross join, and has its drawbacks as well. I was just mentioning the effect with vs without the hardcoded values which will be replaced by the umt_date.  The cross join does work, without doubt but at an expense of performance .